# Bigquery tables.list() returns only 1000 tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

Am I doing something wrong in the following code or is this a bug?

```
 com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Tables.List list =
          bigquery.tables().list(PROJECT_ID, datasetid);
      list.setMaxResults((long) 5000);
      return list.execute().getTables();
```

I have more than a 1000 tables in this dataset.

Comment: *"Am I doing something wrong in the following code or is this a bug?"* Probably neither. It's most likely one of the limits.

Comment: Shouldn't that be specified somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of tables that will be returned in one request is 1000. However, you should also receive a `pageToken` in the response that can be used to page through further results.

as in:

```
List<Table> tables = new ArrayList<>();
com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Tables.List list =
  bigquery.tables().list(PROJECT_ID, datasetid);
list.setMaxResults(5000L);
String nextPageToken = null;
while (true) {
  if (nextPageToken != null) {
    list.setPageToken(nextPageToken);
  }
  TableList result = list.execute();
  tables.addAll(result.getTables());
  if (result.getNextPageToken() == null) {
    break;
  } else {
    nextPageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
  }
}
return tables;
```